# How to get YouCompleteMe to automatically invoke autocomplete

Tags: c++, vim, youcompleteme

I'm running YouCompleteMe on a remote development server with Vim. I'm using the same vimrc as the one on my local system and for whatever reason autocomplete isn't... well.. auto. I can invoke suggestions by adding `let g:ycm_key_invoke_completion = '<C-b>'` to my vimrc. Now if I hit this button in the middle of a symbol it will drop down suggestions but this happens automatically without my intervention on my local system.

I am writing in c++, using CentOS release 6.6, using Vim 7.4 and have no errors when running `:YcmDiags` or `:messages`

Answer (score 1):

The issue seemed to be caused by a [forked version of YCM](https://github.com/oblitum/YouCompleteMe/). Using the [actual version by Valloric](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe) resolved the problem